# OnCreateViewHolder is not being called for the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<>

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I tried to debug my program and noticed that execution is not going inside  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(
                options). I have tried all the possible solutions stackoverflow offered but nothing seems to solve my problem.I m attaching my MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml and if u need any other attachment then just tell me,
thank you

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference myref;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    myref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/blog");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Blog> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Blog>()
                    .setQuery(myref, Blog.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder>(
            options) {
         //this is not being executed
@Override
        public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.individual_row, parent, false);

            return new BlogViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position, Blog model) {
            holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            holder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            holder.setImage(model.getImage());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
}
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    TextView textView_title;
    TextView textView_decription;
    ImageView imageView;
    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;
        textView_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView_decription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        textView_title.setText(title+"");
    }
    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        textView_decription.setText(description);
    }
    public void setImage(String image)
    {
        Picasso.with(mView.getContext())
                .load(image)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/activity_main"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have also tried removing removing sethasfixedsize ...but no luck so far

Comment: Try replacing `parent.getContext()` with `MainActivity.this` and give me your feedback!

Comment: @Xenolion...no luck...execution is skipping to  recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter); directly from  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder>(
            options)

Comment: @Xenolion help please

Comment: Oooh sorry I can not see any error in your code!! I am still wondering where might the problem be!

Comment: can u tell me what is the possible case for which execution is not going inside FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder>( options)

Comment: @Xenolion my app is running but it's not showing any data

Comment: Are you sure the data is there? Or you also do not have data!

Comment: @Xenolion yeah i m sure data is there ... because when i debug, i found that my firebase is connecting to correct URL ... i dont know why it's not showing anything

Comment: help pleasee....waiting for answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late, i hope you had my same error, what you are missing is this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    recyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    recyclerAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

i just lost 2 hours wondering what i was doing wrong and...well it was something like this.

Hope it helps.